# Obtaining symmetric matrices in GAP

Tags: matrices, gap

Let $X$ be a finite set of integers.

> Question: Is there a fast way to obtain all symmetric $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $X$ in GAP?

I try to obtain this set of matrices for example for $n=5$ and $X= \{-1,0,1 \}$ but I get "Error, reached the pre-set memory limit" using GAP. So I wonder whether there is a quick way to obtain such matrices that might be possible also for $n=5$ ($n=4$ takes some minutes).

Comment: There are $|X|^{\binom{n+1}{2}}$ such matrices, which grows enormously quickly. Already at $n=5, |X|=3$ this is 14,348,907. It seems fair for GAP to be complaining about memory. The $n=6, |X|=3$ case is 10,460,353,203, which is likely just unreasonable. (Unfortunately I do not know GAP well enough to say how to work around these issues and iterate over them rather than keeping them all in memory simultaneously.)

Answer (score 2):

Symmetric matrices form a vector space and you can use vector space functionality to construct them. E.g. for $n=2$ and the field with $3$ elements:

```
gap> bas:=[[[1,0],[0,0]],[[0,1],[1,0]],[[0,0],[0,1]]]*One(GF(3));;
gap> v:=VectorSpace(GF(3),bas);
<vector space over GF(3), with 3 generators>
gap> e:=Enumerator(v);
<enumerator of <vector space of dimension 3 over GF(3)>>
gap> Length(e);
27
gap> Display(e[15]);
 1 1
 1 2
```

You can use this enumerator `e` like a list, but it uses far less memory. Converting from finite field to integer entries will be easy.